# How can I restore a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a Form application which is written in C#. How can I hide a form and then restore it?

Form 1:

```
private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
}
```

Form 2:

```
private void BackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    //code which shows again form1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to have a reference to the first form (Form1 in your example) so that you can call the Show() method against it.

A simple approach might be to have a property on Form2 that you assign with a reference to the first form.